# Replace a line with multiple lines in a file

Tags: bash, unix, sed, ed

I want to replace a single line in a file with multiple lines, e.g., I want to replace a particular function call, say,

```
foo(1,2)
```

with

```
if (a > 1) {  
    foo(1,2)  
} else {  
    bar(1,2)  
}
```

How can I do it in bash?

Comment: what if I want to change it inplace in my current file without creating any extra file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what the sed `s` command was built for:

```
shopt -s extglob

ORIG="foo(1,2)"
REP="if (a > 1) {  
      foo(1,2)  
} else {  
      bar(1,2)  
}"

REP="${REP//+(
)/\\n}"

sed "s/$ORIG/$REP/g" inputfile > outputfile
```

Note that the `REP="${REP//\+( )/\\n}"` lines are only needed if you want to define the `REP` in the formatted way that I did on line two.  It might be simpler if you just used `\n` and `\t` in `REP` to begin with.

Edit: Note! You need to escape `'` and `\` as well in your REP if you have them.

***Edit in response to the OP's question***

To change your original file without creating a new file, use sed's `--in-place` flag, like so:

```
sed --in-place "s/$ORIG/$REP/g" inputfile
```

Please be careful with the `--in-place` flag.  Make backups before you run it because all changes will be permanent.

Comment: `shopt -s extglob` is required and the backslash before the plus sign needs to be removed.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Thanks for catching that.  I forget sometimes that most people don't have extended globbing turned on by default.  The backslash was just leftover from testing.

Comment: It is working, but I am not sure what this meant   
`REP="${REP//+(  
)/\\n}"`

Comment: @ravi It's a from of [Parameter Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) called "Global Replacement".

Comment: Note if you e.g. have an apostrophe in your REP it will also brake sed. You will get something like: `sed: -e expression #1, char 320: unknown option to \`s'`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
cat <<\! |
> a
> foo(1,2)
> b
> foo(1,2)
> c
> !
> sed '/foo(1,2)/c\
> if (a > 1) {\
>     foo(1,2)\
> } else {\
>     bar(1,2)\
> }' 
a
if (a > 1) {
    foo(1,2)
} else {
    bar(1,2)
}
b
if (a > 1) {
    foo(1,2)
} else {
    bar(1,2)
}
c
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace strings in-place in a file, you can use ed (as conveniently tagged in the question). Assuming your input file looks like this:

```
line before
foo(1,2)
line between
    foo(1,2)
line after
```

You can write a script to do the substitution and store it in a file such as `script.ed`:

```
%s/\([[:blank:]]*\)foo(1,2)/\1if (a > 1) {\
\1    foo(1,2)\
\1} else {\
\1    bar(1,2)\
\1}/
w
q
```

Notice that this takes indentation into account; every line is prepended with whatever blanks were there before the function call in the original file, so the result would look like this:

```
$ ed -s infile < script.ed
$ cat infile
line before
if (a > 1) {
    foo(1,2)
} else {
    bar(1,2)
}
line between
    if (a > 1) {
        foo(1,2)
    } else {
        bar(1,2)
    }
line after
```

Should the function call not be on a line on its own but potentially prepended by other characters that shouldn't be removed, you could use this as the first line of the substitution:

```
%s/\([[:blank:]]*\)\(.*\)foo(1,2)/\1\2if (a > 1) {\
```

So this

```
    } something; foo(1,2)
```

would become

```
    } something; if (a > 1) {
        foo(1,2)
    } else {
        bar(1,2)
    }
```

with indentation still properly accounted for.